# Find image of $D=\{z: |z|<1\}$ under $f(z)={z\over z-1}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find image of $D=\{z: |z|<1\}$ under $f(z)={z\over z-1}$. I know it is supposed to be $\Re z <{1\over 2}$, but unfortunately I've been trying to show this for too long and my sanity along with my concentration drops monotonically. I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways :the easiest seems to be 
$$f(1)=\infty $$
 $$  f(-1)=1/2$$ and 
$$f(i)=1/2 - i/2 $$Hence the line $\Re{z}=1/2 $  is the image of the unit circle.Hence the range is $\Re {z} <1/2$ since $f(0)=0$.

Comment: You need a better argument to affirm that $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \Re z=\frac{1}{2}\}$ is the image by $f$ of the unit circle than taking the image of three points on the unit circle and seeing that they indeed have a real part strictly inferior to $\frac{1}{2}$. Moreover, after that, you may  need to add an argument to explain with this shows that the image by $f$ of $D$ is indeed $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \Re z<\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Comment: Möbius transformation--so bijective and takes circles to line or circles(3 points is enough to determine] and connectedness of the images of outside/inside of unit circle..this is why the standard method works..

Comment: The best would have been to write it correctly in your answer, especially as your idea is really good.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. We have
$$\frac{z}{z-1}=\frac{x+\mathrm{i}y}{(x-1)+\mathrm{i}y}=\frac{x(x-1)+y^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}-\mathrm{i}\frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$
so
\begin{align}
\Re\frac{z}{z-1} & =\frac{x(x-1)+y^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\\
& =\frac{x^2+y^2-x}{x^2+y^2-2x+1}\\
& < \frac{1-x}{2-2x}\\
& =\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-x}{1-x}\\
& =\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
whence $f\left(D\right)\subset\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \Re z<\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Now take $\omega=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon\right)+\mathrm{i}y$ with $\varepsilon>0$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$. We can check that $f$ is an involution, that is $f$ is bijective and $f^{-1}=f$, so we see that we can choose $z=\frac{\omega}{\omega-1}$ to have $f(z)=\omega$. Moreover, this choice is licit since
\begin{align}
|z| & =\left|\frac{\omega}{\omega-1}\right|\\
& =\frac{\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon\right)+\mathrm{i}y\right|}{\left|-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\right)+\mathrm{i}y\right|}\\
& = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon\right)^2+y^2}{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\right)^2+y^2}\\
& = \frac{\frac{1}{4}+\varepsilon^2+y^2-\varepsilon}{\frac{1}{4}+\varepsilon^2+y^2+\varepsilon}\\
& <1.
\end{align}
Hence, we have $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \Re z<\frac{1}{2}\}\subset f\left(D\right)$.